# Modeling typology for sharp/diamond like objects

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

I've been trying to modeling this simple diamond shape for a couple hours and I can't seem to figure out a way to model it with good edgeflow and for it to be sub-dividable. Its such a frustratingly simple model as well!!

I always tend to always have trouble keeping everything as quads when it comes to objects that end in sharp corners like these. My most intuitive attempt was starting from a basic pyramid primitive but, that wont subdivide properly.

Any tips about topology and edgeflow guys?

[image: Diamond Shape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

You can do this in couple different ways. I'll present you two of them, and both non destructive.

### Base mesh:

As a base mesh you'll need to create diamond shape with triangle-like quads (yes, they are ok, and they are still quads).

[image: base]

### Mean Crease method:

Select outer/sharp edges and add to them [**Mean Crease**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html) - I've used 0.96 for base of the mesh (square) and 0.8 for the side ones.

After that add **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

[image: mean]

### Bevel modifier method:

This one is simpler and recommended.

Add **Bevel** modifier, choose **Limit Method > Angle**. Set number of **Segments** and **Width**.

Add **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

[image: bevel]

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Great screenshots its been really helpful

Comment: In recreating your topo, I'm having trouble seeing the purpose of the central vertex in each face.  Degenerate quads like this *can* cause problems (I've perosnally seen them lead to bone heat failures from autoweights, although that might not happen in this case) and, to my knowledge, provide none of the benefits of quad modelling.  Can you maybe provide some information about why it's better to use those extra vertices?